# use ajax call in jquery autocomplete only if result is not found in locally built array

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

In my web app , I am showing rates of stocks.I am using jquery autocomplete to show options while entring stocks name. But I have built local copy of javascript array. I want to show the options from this local array , If search term is not found in local array then ajax call must be made to get the list from server side.

Thanks !!!

```
     //Local array
     var local_array=["option1","option2"];

     //jqueryUI call of autocomplete function
     $('#search_stock').autocomplete({
     source:function(){
                 if(search term is found in local array)
                 {
                     show suggestion from local array.
                 }
                 else
                 {
                      make ajax call to show suggestions of stock names.
                 }
            }
       });
```

**UPDATE**

Here's the actual code

```
$(function() {
  var cache = {'option1':'option1','option2':'option2'}, lastXhr;
  $( "#stock_rates" ).autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: function( request, response ) {
      var term = request.term;
      if ( term in cache ) {
        response( cache[ term ] );
        return;
      }
      lastXhr = $.getJSON( "stock_rates.php", request, function( data, status, xhr ) {
        cache[ term ] = data;
        if ( xhr === lastXhr ) { response( data ); }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The example pages for jQuery UI autocomplete have an example of exactly this issue.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-with-cache. Click the 'View Source' link on that page to see the code for the example.

The key part is that 'source' takes arguments.

```
source: function(request, response){
```

You need to read `request`, either fetch the value from your cache, or do a request, and then call the `response` function and pass it the matched values.

**Update**

Your problem now is that the format that you are storing in your cache is wrong. The cache just stores data as it would be returned from your getJSON call, indexed by the search term. It is up to you do to do the prefix checking and such.

To continue the way you are trying now, you'll either need to populate the cache properly.

```
var cache = {
  "o": ['option1', 'option2'],
  "op": ['option1', 'option2'],
  // ....
  "option1": ['option1'],
  "option2": ['option2']
};
```

Otherwise, you could store the data differently and put more logic in your 'source' function to do the prefix checking on a static array or something. That all really depends on the data you are caching though.

Comment: thanks for ur effort & tym to ans :) I hve tried 'remote-with-cache' but its not working with prebuilt array or javascript object.Its working with cache object build at runtym, but m trying the same with hardcoaded object , i cant figure out y its not working

Comment: @user755255 Can you give us some more info then? Are you getting any javascript errors? What is the actual code you are using? Try to give some code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Here is the code Segment :     <script> $(function() { var cache = {'option1':'option1','option2':'option2'}, lastXhr; $( "#stock_rates" ).autocomplete({ minLength: 2, source: function( request, response ) { var term = request.term; if ( term in cache ) { response( cache[ term ] ); return; } lastXhr = $.getJSON( "stock_rates.php", request, function( data, status, xhr ) { cache[ term ] = data; if ( xhr === lastXhr ) { response( data ); } }); } }); }); </script>

Comment: @user755255 If you `console.log(data)`, what is it? Is the Ajax request actually returning? Does your comparison of `xhr` actually pass? Also, in the future paste code into the question. I edited it this time.

Comment: yup ajax is returning json data and xhr is passing the condition.But summary of problem is "Even though the stock name to find is existed in the locally built object , it calls for an ajax call." I really feel obliged by ur concern, bt can u plz give try to the autocomplete UI plugin with hardcoded javascript object.I am breaking my head in it and now trying to implement same in asp.net solution. Thanks 4 all !!! :)

Comment: @user755255 Yeah, I think I misread something at some point, sorry. I've updated my answer.

Comment: ur suggestion are pretty awesome !!! bt i again reached the same point coz formating the cache as u suggested is obsolete & absurd for 50 or 60 stock_names.So can u plz give reference or ne code sample which use prebuilt array as primary data source for autocomplete and if data not found in primary array then ajax call mst be made to show the autocomplete suggestions ??? Thanks :)

Comment: @Vivek That's where I'm a bit confused. I don't know if you've fully thought through the implications of that. How would you decide what things to preload and what things not to? For example if you cache  'option1' and 'option2', but NOT 'option3', when do you run the AJAX request? A user typing 'o' would expect to see all 3, but since only two are preloaded, it would see two, and since something matched, it wouldn't fire the ajax request. That means someone may have already typed out most of what they want before the AJAX request would fire, unless you've cached *everything* already.

Comment: @Vivek My point is that pre-filling the cache requires a bit more thinking, and a better understanding of the data being loaded.

Comment: Ok i got ur confusion.lets dive in real things. I want to mke a hardcoded array of popular stock_names lyke (Wipro,Microsoft etc).So daat if user typ in d popular stock_names thn 1st 5-6 option wud come in first place and as last option i wud give link to anther page where all d posible outcome wud show.It prity same as facebook search. In which on page load they load the built an array of frndlist and when u search first 5-6 option are shown quickly widout ajax call and as a last suggestion dey have link to search page showing all suggestion.Thanks for asking for clarification

Comment: one more thing if search term is not contained in ur frndlist of facebook then ajax call is made in first place to show appropriate suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Use search event of autocomplete and check your condition in that event and based on that return true or false if you want to make a ajax call respectively.

Below is the sample code.

```
$('#search_stock').autocomplete({
 search:function(event,ui){
             if(search term is found in local array)
             {
                 return false;
             }
             else
             {
                 return true;
             }
        }
   });
```